# google apps script looping with message boxes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, prompt

I am working on a project involving user input. I am checking to see if the answer provided is equal to a set answer. I want them to keep answering until they get the answer right. Instead of having a bunch of if statements I want to use a loop. I have tried several loops but all of them just keep going on indefinitely. Here are the programs I've tried (I didn't try a *for* loop because it didn't seem applicable).

```
function answer(){
    var input = Browser.inputBox('Please submit your answer');
    while(input != 1){
    input = Browser.inputBox('your answer was incorect, please try again');
    }
Browser.msgBox('good job you got the right answer!')
}
```

I also tried

```
function answer(){
    var input = Browser.inputBox('Please submit your answer');
    do{
    input = Browser.inputBox('your answer was incorect, please try again');
    }while(input != 1);
Browser.msgBox('good job you got the right answer!')
}
```

I know that the *do while* loop will have them submit two answers but I was just experimenting. Any help would be appreciated.

**In simplifying it I removed the problem so here is the code I am having problems with.

```
function answer(){
    var input = Browser.inputBox('Please submit your answer');
    var range1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheet1).getRange('A1');
    var range2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheet1).getRange('B1');
    range1.setValue(input);
    var answer = range2.getValue();

    while(answer != 'correct'){
        input = Browser.inputBox('your answer was incorect, please try again');
        range1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheet1).getRange('A1');
        range2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheet1).getRange('B1');
        range1.setValue(input);
        answer = range2.getValue();
    }

    Browser.msgBox('good job you got the right answer!')
}
```

This code refers to the spreadsheet to do the calculations which seems to throw off the loops and cause them to go into an infinite loop. In B1 I have it run the calculations and display correct or incorrect based on what is in A1. I ran it and waited. After about 5-10 minutes my script gave me a *timed out waiting for user response (line 2, file "Code")* error. I watched the spreadsheet the entire time and it never gave me an input-box.

Comment: I just copied and pasted your first code block into GAS and it worked as expected. Is there a different problem you're seeing?

Comment: @Brian I clarified my question, thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you expect `B2` to be changing, there is no reason to do `getRange('B1')` and `.getValue()` repeatedly, but that's not the problem, just some optimization.

Now on to your problem. It's a flaw in your code logic

```
while(answer != 'correct')
```

in your script `answer` is the value in `B2` however you do not change this value with your input, thus if `B2` value is `correct` it will always run once, however, if `B2` is **not** `correct` then it will loop indefinitely.

**EDIT**
I changed the code a bit to what I assume you want it to do with a few optimisations. Removed the unnecessary `getRange()` and `.getSheet` repeats

```
function answer(){
  var objSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var objUi = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var input = objUi.prompt('Please submit your answer').getResponseText();

  var range1 = objSheet.getRange('A1');
  var range2 = objSheet.getRange('B1');  

  range1.setValue(input);
  var answer = range2.getValue();

  while (input != answer){
    input = objUi.prompt('Your answer was incorect, please try again').getResponseText();
    range1.setValue(input);
  }

  objUi.alert('good job you got the right answer!')
}
```